# FFmpeg и веб обвязка

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg

Нужно создать веб обвязку которая будет посылать команды FFmpeg на RPi для записи видео, далее получать информацию о видео, показывать эти видео на самой странице, создание скриншотов из видео и так же показ их на сайте. Все это будет делать RPi без какой либо помощи другого сервера.

Поставил на него первым делом nginx; Теперь прежде чем начат работать над самой веб обвязкой,
подскажите, если ли возможность получения информации о видео, послание команд и тд, с помощью js?

Comment: RPi это raspeberry pi? Если да хватает ли мощности?

Comment: @JK_Action да и да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внешнего управления через веб я не встречал, думаю вам придется какой-то бэкэнд городить Rest или Websocket сервис. Хотя я бы на вашем месте искал надстройку медиа сервер.

Comment: нашел что-то такое http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/index.php посмотрим